# Liferay login with internal users and ldap users

Tags: authentication, ldap, liferay

i want to customize login in Liferay 6.2. I've internal liferay users and ldap users. All users have a record in liferay user_ table. The differences are: internal users must change password at first login and see password reminder question.
Ldap users make only login with their password. 
Acutally Liferay ask to ldap users to change their password and set password reminder question. These users change password but at next login, login is possible by old ldap password (correct). Liferay must not write in ldap.
How can i remove password change and password reminder question for ldap user?

Answer (score 1):

There's a password policy that you can set per organization. If you introduce a new organization for each of the groups (or just one might suffice as well) you can have individual password policies per organization.

In Password policies you can configure quite a lot of stuff, e.g. should passwords be changed on first login etc. You can also select the "LDAP Password Policy" in the LDAP configuration screen. I'm rarely working with password policies, thus it's hard to give detailed directions - let me know if this is sufficient or if you need more detailed pointers